# SQL: Update multiple rows with data from spreadsheet

Tags: t-sql

I have a contact table that I need to update based on data contained within a spreadsheet - the spreadsheet contains the key in the table, and the new value.

| AlternateID | Email |
| --- | --- |
| NW01_1301_001 | nicktest001testemail.com |
| NW01_1301_002 | nicktest002testemail.com |

etc

Currently, I'm concatenating that data within the spreadsheet to create a list of multiple update statements using

```
="update contact set email = '"&B2&"' where alternateID = '"&B1&"'"
```

to give:

```
Begin Tran
update contact set email = 'nicktest001testemail.com' where alternateID = 'NW01_1301_001'
update contact set email = 'nicktest002testemail.com' where alternateID = 'NW01_1301_002'
update contact set email = 'nicktest003testemail.com' where alternateID = 'NW01_1301_003'
...
update contact set email = 'nicktest004testemail.com' where alternateID = 'NW01_1301_999'
--commit
```

and whilst this works fine for smaller datasets - as the number of records increases, so too does the hit on the database.

I have a similar task, where we're deleting records:

```
Begin Tran
delete contact where alternateID = 'NW01_1301_001'
delete contact where alternateID = 'NW01_1301_002'
delete contact where alternateID = 'NW01_1301_003'
...
delete contact where alternateID = 'NW01_1301_999'
--commit
```

which is even worse!

Is there a way to bulk update using 'in ('range')' that minimizes the manipulation in excel and allows to copy/paste both the updated values and the where criteria?

Edit: it would also be useful if I could output progress using Print to show how many records have been updated

Many thanks in advance

Nick

Answer (score 0):

You would save some time if you were to use Transactions. [Guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/t_sql/t_sql_transactions.htm).

For your second one, you'd likely be better with the below as it won't be a separate query each time.

```
delete from table where col in('value1','value2'...);
```

However, doing large operations will always take a large amount of time. The time to do 10 will be shorter than 100, which will be shorter than 1000 etc.

Comment: thanks for that - I should clarify, I am using Begin Tran/Commit :)